# How to fade a Cesium.PolylineArrowMaterialProperty

Tags: cesiumjs

Im trying to fade the Cesium.PolylineArrowMaterialProperty but cant find any documentation that cesium talks about solving this issue. Does anyone have any ideas on doing this? Basically a way to make the polyline transparent.

Comment: Do you mean a constant alpha value, across the whole line, or are you asking for a changing value that makes one side opaque and the other fully transparent?

Comment: Yes, you basically read my mind lol.